# How to store and retrieve secret in AWX for inventory script?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-awx

I have a dynamic inventory script based on a MariaDB database. It works as expected when I call it from Ansible and now I want to use it with AWX as an inventory source from a project. But I can't figure out how to store my database credentials and how to retrieve them from the script.

Currently I use a json file with my credentials, anyway I don't want to store these data on the Git repository. So I'm stuck at that point: I have a script that works, but I can't use it in AWX because I didn't find any way to retrieve secrets from the inventory script.

Do you have some advices to give to me?

Comment: Are you willing to convert your inventory script to an inventory plugin ? Because in that case the solution is quite straightforward as you will be able to encrypt your credentials directly in the plugin config file using ansible-vault (either the data strings themselves inside a human readable file or the full config file if you wish).

Comment: You don't want to store encrypted ansible vault secrets in git, do I understand correctly?

Comment: @Zeitounator: How can I retrieve vault-encrypted data as I don't have any inventory at this time?

Comment: @JiriB: I'm agree that storing vault encrypted data could be the solution, but how can I retrieve that data from the inventory script?

Comment: @D.Gonçalves if you have a dynamic inventory plugin, you have a dynamic inventory yaml configuration file. You can have vault encrypted info in there. And this is just one possibility.

Comment: Ansible Vault secrets are just variables as anything else. Take them as the varibles. Thus if you use one inventory file, put them there, if you use (preferred) more structured layout (see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#content-organization) put them into host_vars/group_vars paths.

Comment: @D.Gonçalves I just made a quickNdirty demo of a dummy inventory plugin to illustrate you can have vault encrypted vars in your configuration file and get them back in your script. For the demo, I just added those vars back to specific vars on localhost in the dynamic inventory and print them in a debug task: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/a90d16314e590bfc5cb228e7a693e990

Comment: @Zeitounator: thanks a lot that's exactly what I expected :)